# what happen IF condition is executing and interrupt is came?

Tags: microcontroller

suppose i have condition if( a & b).
during execution if it execute A variable after that interrupt is occur.
so is it complete the if condition means till B variable and after that go for that interrupt or is it stop executing till a variable and after complete interrupt it back to B variable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you're describing C/Java/some-HLL, your CPU is executing machine code instructions. (HLL is High-Level Language.)

When the CPU services the interrupt, it will complete the instruction it is executing, save some of the program state and subroutine-call an Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). The ISR must complete its task and return from the interrupt. The CPU will restore the program state and should carry on executing the main program as if nothing had happened.

The lines of your program are made up of one or more CPU instructions. You can see this by looking into the debugger or output files from your compiler and seeing the lines of assembly language generated for each program line. (1 assembly language line is 1 CPU instruction.)

The various parts of an if-then-else-end clause (or equivalent for your HLL) are all carried out by these CPU instructions. There is nothing more special about getting an interrupt anywhere during there - the interrupt can occur anywhere.

Comment: There're cases when interrupt is being serviced *during* CPU instruction execution as seen from assembly programming poit of view - in string operations in x86 interrupt may be invoked if `rep` prefix is present; in z80 if string instruction is having `R` at the end (e.g. LDIR)

Comment: The LDIR/LDDR/CPIR/CPDR/OTIR/OTDR opcodes are refetched on every pass (byte move). That's what makes them so slow. They're not in some state loop, they just put the PC to the start every pass. The 8086 REP opcodes are re-executed on program resume.

Comment: yaa @TonyM i have one more doubt if i have Rtos. and in Rtos there are different time slicing of task. so suppose in some task there is same if condition present and time slicing of same task is complete.so in that case what happen is that complete if condition  or go to another task??please elaborate this one also.

Comment: @DipeshKayastha, time-slicing uses an interrupt and the suspended program acts like its had an interrupt between runs - so there's no difference, the explanation above covers it. I think your confusion is that you don't understand the idea of machine code instructions on a CPU, and how they relate to your HLL. You need to read up on your own about this, I can't teach you it here and there's plenty of well-written text on the internet. Get ready to spend days or weeks understanding it - it's worth it :-)